# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\StateException' with message 'Invalid state

Tags: sms, ovh, guzzle

I ve got this error :

> Blockquote
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\StateException' with message 'Invalid state: before' in /home/julienlakq/custom/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php:65 Stack trace: #0 
>   Blockquote

When trying to run a script to send sms.

Has someone seen this kind of error ?
And what this mean ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Any update ? The OVH API provider does not provide support on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to fix it by editing the Guzzle API.

In ./vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php line 58, 
change the switch evaluation value to `switch(trim(strtolower($trans->state)))`

It may indicate an encoding problem or a bug in the OVH or Guzzle library.